# Web Service Authentication with Digital Signature/ Certificate in Android

Tags: java, android, web-services, ssl, soap

We're trying to Authenticate a SOAP Web Service in Android through the Digital Signature (Cryptography mechanism) and Digital Certificates.

In normal J2EE Application, we almost achieved this with Apache CXF along with WSS4J (Implements primary Security Standards).

However in Android, We're currently consuming the SOAP Web Servcies through stubs generated through easyWSDL. Apache CXF jars aren't supported in Android and we can't rely on them.

Kindly let me know how to authenticate Web Service in Andorid?